# Safety guidelines to using MS Office with Wine on Linux

Tags: wine, playonlinux

People at my institution keep sending me Office files from time to time. Sometimes Powerpoint presentations, sometimes Excel sheets or even Word documents, and I have to edit them.

And no, Libreoffice is not 100% compatible. When they get my edited version back they usually say: What the f**k did you do with this? It's all messed up!!

I have a limited license to one of the MS Office products and my options are either a Playonlinux (Wine) installation or using it inside a virtual machine.

The Wine option is nice. However I remember from my old times as Windows user that some sorts of viruses could arrive inside Excel macros (this was back in the times of Windows NT Workstation 4, so things might have changed, I don't know).

Hence my question: since a wine program has full access to my home, how should I manage the **need** (please avoid the unreal and unacceptable "Libreoffice is fully compatible" which I myself would love to be the truth but it isn't, thanks) to install MS Office in my laptop while staying safe from viruses? Should I restrict the MS Office programs to a virtual machine with read-only access to anything outside it, and after each use erase the full machine and import it again from an image? Or am I safe having those MS Office programs installed by Playonlinux (Wine) without any antivirus software and with full access to all files in my home? Why?

Comment: This reminds me of one of the most important reasons to be a Linux user, namely staying away from the constant paranoia of viruses

Comment: If markup of documents is not difficult you can MS Office online (no it's not Office 365 which you need to buy): https://office.live.com. Just create MS account and use it. Sometimes I see and edit MS document in this manner.

Comment: I'm not sure you're exactly *staying away from* paranoia of viruses...

Comment: @MichaelHomer Hahaha +1

Comment: Probably you should post your question at [Security StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions)